# Cumulative distinct count in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column called `group` and another column called `country`. I want to create a new column that outputs a cumulative count of distinct values in the `country` column whilst grouping on the `group` column

Original dataframe:

```
group        country
A            usa
A            germany
A            germany
A            france
A            usa
B            germany
B            germany
B            france
B            germany
B            france
```

New dataframe:

```
group        country       num_distinct_values
A            usa           1
A            germany       2
A            germany       2
A            france        3
A            usa           3
B            germany       1
B            germany       1
B            france        2  
B            germany       2
B            france        2
```

I have tried using the duplicated method along with cumcount and cumsum but I can't seem to use these methods to get what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
df['num_distinct_values'] = (~df.duplicated()).groupby(df['group']).cumsum()
```

If you have other columns, make sure to only use group+country to identify the unique values:

```
cols = ['group', 'country']
df['num_distinct_values'] = (~df.duplicated(subset=cols)
                             ).groupby(df['group']).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
  group  country  num_distinct_values
0     A      usa                    1
1     A  germany                    2
2     A  germany                    2
3     A   france                    3
4     A      usa                    3
5     B  germany                    1
6     B  germany                    1
7     B   france                    2
8     B  germany                    2
9     B   france                    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using cumcount and cumsum. We find all the first occurences of the value in the row and then we count these up using cumsum:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "group": ["A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
    "country": ["usa", "germany", "germany", "france", "usa", "germany", "germany", "france", "germany", "france"]
})
df["first_seen_country"] = df.groupby(["group", "country"]).cumcount()==0
df["num_distinct_values"] = df.groupby(["group"])["first_seen_country"].cumsum()
```

Comment: Have you tried [my approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77017658/16343464)? It should be more efficient

Comment: Oh yes I think you are right. I did personally think my solution was slightly more readable but yes I think yours is more efficient.