# How to create a column that counts unique instances of a another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to create a column `length/type_count` that counts the number of unique instances of the variable `length/type` that appears within an `Over`. A new `over` starts every six `deliveries_faced`. Therefore the count would need to reset after every 6 deliveries at the start of every over as shown below

```
                                                        length/type   length/type_count
Batfast_id Session_no Event_name Overs deliveries_faced  
   player1          1        ful     1                0      S_S_Y           1
                                                      1      S_S_Y           1
                                                      2      M_S_Y           2
                                                      3      M_OS_F          3
                                                      4      M_S_Y           3
                                                      5      F_LS_Y          4
                                      2               6      M_S_F           1
                                                      7      S_S_ES          2
                                                      8      S_S_ES          2
                                                      9      S_S_ES          2
                                                      10      F_S_Y          3
                                                      11      F_S_Y          3
```

`Batfast_id` `Session_no` `Event_name` `Overs` `deliveries_faced` are an index, however the columns are also contained within the dataset

Comment: Can you please provide a DataFrame constructor of your input?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, here is one possible option :

```
df['length/type_count'] = (df.reset_index().duplicated(subset=['Over', 'length/type_count'])
                             .set_axis(df.index).groupby(level='Over').cumsum()
                          )
```

Output :

```
print(df)

                                                        length/type  length/type_count
Batfast_id Session_no Event_name overs deliveries_faced                               
player1    1          ful        1     0                      S_S_Y                  1
                                       1                      S_S_Y                  1
                                       2                      M_S_Y                  2
                                       3                     M_OS_F                  3
                                       4                      M_S_Y                  3
                                       5                     F_LS_Y                  4
                                 2     6                      M_S_F                  1
                                       7                     S_S_ES                  2
                                       8                     S_S_ES                  2
                                       9                     S_S_ES                  2
                                       10                     F_S_Y                  3
                                       11                     F_S_Y                  3
```

Comment: **NB** : This assumes `df.index.nlevels` equals to `5` (with *labeled indexes*).

Comment: I am finding that it works in some overs and others it does not giving zeros and /or the wrong count

Comment: I knew I had answered a similar question [not long ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77017658/16343464) ;)

Comment: @Yoseph you need to pass the relevant groups (+`['length/type']`) as subset to `duplicated`

Comment: @mozway unfortunately what you suggested gave the same result. If you closed the question would really appreciate if you reopened it as i still do not have a solution

Comment: @YosephIsmail if you provide a reproducible example that demonstrates that this doesn't work I'll happily reopen (make sure to test the last update of Timeless' answer) ;)

Comment: I have found the solution, thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

I thinks that something like this will work for you:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a mask to identify the start of a new over
    mask = (df['overs'] != df['overs'].shift(1)) | (df['deliveries_faced'] % 6 == 0)

# Group by relevant columns and calculate the unique count of 'Event_name' within each over
df['length/type_count'] = df.groupby(['Batfast_id', 'Session_no', 'Event_name', mask.cumsum()])['Event_name'].transform('nunique')

print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this just counts each delivery like 1,2,3,4,5,6 but does not count the unique instances of a delivery like above

Comment: Checkit now, i think that does it with the cumsum method

Comment: This now just gives 1,1,1,1,1,1. Please note tho that when the variable name appears in the index it begins with a capital letter and when a column a lowercase letter